# Loop for generating lottery numbers

Tags: r, loops, random, sample

I am working with R and using the expression `sort(sample(1:60,6,replace=FALSE))` for generating 6 numbers between 1 and 60, without replacement...

I would like to create a loop using FOR statements that allow to generate n different samples, using the logic above.

Any suggestion about how to build this loop?

Answer (score 3):

Use `replicate`:

```
replicate(sort(sample(1:60, 6, replace = FALSE)), n = 1000)
```

The result is a matrix of size 6x1000, so each column is one sample.

I guess you want to do random draws which would allow equal samples. In case you do want unique samples, I gave it a shot:

```
lottery <- function(n) {
  S <- replicate(sort.int(sample(1:60, 6, repl = F)), n = n)
  while(d <- anyDuplicated(S, MARGIN = 2)) {
    S <- cbind(S[, -d], sort.int(sample(1:60, 6, repl = F)))
  }
  S
}
```

Comment: I understand but why would you have 2 lottery tickets with same numbers?

Comment: As it turns out, rarely, this is the case in the real world as well ;) Lets see what OP has to say to clarify.

Comment: The question say "generate n different samples", so @zx8754 is right

Comment: That is what is written there, which is not always the same as what an OP means.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `rerun` function that returns a list with the result that you need

```
library(purrr)

rerun(.n = 1000, sort(sample(1:60, 6, replace = FALSE))) %>%
  unique()
```